# Ask for help to go to the fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have used in my project of bottomnavigation.
I want to when you click on any of the icons below to go to the new fragment. My 
I thank you for the tips here!
code is as follows:

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TabLayout mTabLayout;

    private int[] mTabsIcons = {
            R.drawable.ic_recents_selector,
            R.drawable.ic_favorite_selector,
            R.drawable.ic_place_selector};


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Setup the viewPager
        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        MyPagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        if (viewPager != null)
            viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

        mTabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        if (mTabLayout != null) {
            mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

            for (int i = 0; i < mTabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
                TabLayout.Tab tab = mTabLayout.getTabAt(i);
                if (tab != null)
                    tab.setCustomView(pagerAdapter.getTabView(i));
            }

            mTabLayout.getTabAt(0).getCustomView().setSelected(true);
        }
    }


    private class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public final int PAGE_COUNT = 3;

        private final String[] mTabsTitle = {"Recents", "Favorites", "Nearby"};

        public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        public View getTabView(int position) {
            // Given you have a custom layout in `res/layout/custom_tab.xml` with a TextView and ImageView
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
            TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
            title.setText(mTabsTitle[position]);
            ImageView icon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            icon.setImageResource(mTabsIcons[position]);
            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
            switch (pos) {

                case 0:
                    return PageFragment.newInstance(1);

                case 1:
                    return PageFragment.newInstance(2);
                case 2:
                    return PageFragment.newInstance(3);

            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return PAGE_COUNT;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mTabsTitle[position];
        }
    }

}
```

PageFragment

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TabLayout mTabLayout;

    private int[] mTabsIcons = {
            R.drawable.ic_recents_selector,
            R.drawable.ic_favorite_selector,
            R.drawable.ic_place_selector};


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Setup the viewPager
        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        MyPagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        if (viewPager != null)
            viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

        mTabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        if (mTabLayout != null) {
            mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

            for (int i = 0; i < mTabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
                TabLayout.Tab tab = mTabLayout.getTabAt(i);
                if (tab != null)
                    tab.setCustomView(pagerAdapter.getTabView(i));
            }

            mTabLayout.getTabAt(0).getCustomView().setSelected(true);
        }
    }


    private class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public final int PAGE_COUNT = 3;

        private final String[] mTabsTitle = {"Recents", "Favorites", "Nearby"};

        public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        public View getTabView(int position) {
            // Given you have a custom layout in `res/layout/custom_tab.xml` with a TextView and ImageView
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
            TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
            title.setText(mTabsTitle[position]);
            ImageView icon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            icon.setImageResource(mTabsIcons[position]);
            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
            switch (pos) {

                case 0:
                    return PageFragment.newInstance(1);

                case 1:
                    return PageFragment.newInstance(2);
                case 2:
                    return PageFragment.newInstance(3);

            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return PAGE_COUNT;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mTabsTitle[position];
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not figure out exactly what your problem was from your question but I think I somewhat understood what you are trying to do and here's a simple way I use

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Set the content of the activity to use the activity_main.xml layout file
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Find the view pager that will allow the user to swipe between fragments
    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

    // Create an adapter that knows which fragment should be shown on each page
    SimpleFragmentPagerAdapter adapter = new SimpleFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);

    // Set the adapter onto the view pager
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
}
```

SimpleFragmentPagerAdapter.java

```
public class SimpleFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private String tabTitles[] = new String[] { "Numbers", "Family", "Colors","Phrases" };


    public SimpleFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        if (position == 0) {
            return new NumbersFragment();
        } else if (position == 1){
            return new FamilyFragment();
        } else if (position == 2) {
            return new ColorsFragment();
        }else {
            return new PhrasesFragment();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 4;
    }
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        // Generate title based on item position
        return tabTitles[position];
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.android.miwok.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/primary_color"
    app:tabBackground="@color/primary_color"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/tan_background"
    app:tabGravity="center"
    app:tabMode="fixed"
    app:tabTextColor="#A8A19E"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="#FFFFFF"
     />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```